# Passing data and auto create iframe in window.open every click

Tags: php, ajax

How can I pass data to another page and automatically creates an iframe to my popup window every time I click?

This is my JavaScript code in parent.

```
var wo;
function dd(id) {
    if (wo && !wo.closed) {
       wo.focus();
       var ids = 'lots=' + id;
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'tuk.php',
            data: ids,
            success: function() {
            }
        });
    }
    else {
       wo = window.open("tuk.php?lots="+id,"","width=200,height=200");      
    }
}
```

This is my child.

```
<?php isset($_POST['lots']) ? $lotsid = $_POST['lots'] : $lotsid = $_GET['lots'];?>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
dd()
    function dd() {
        var wrap= document.createElement("iframe");
        wrap.setAttribute("src", "<?php echo $lotsid;?>");
        wrap.style.width = "49%";
        wrap.style.height = "49%";
        document.body.appendChild(wrap);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try to do something ?

Comment: not yet sir,can u suggest sir ?.

Comment: Not right now, we like to see people try first.

Comment: last question sir,how can i get the data from my parent,and my window get it ,because the first click is the only one that getting it. thank you sir.

Comment: What does this do, instead of working?

Answer (score 0):

This should be your main page sample code

```
    <input type="button" value="Click me to open iframe" id="clk_btn"/>

</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#clk_btn',function(){
            dd(123);
        });
        var wo;
        function dd(id) {
            if (wo && !wo.closed) {
                // whatever you want to do here 
            }
            else {
                wo = window.open("iframe.php?lots="+id,"","width=200,height=200");      
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

write what ever you do in iframe.php

Comment: `id` is undefined

Comment: pass id what you want to post to next page for example

$(document).on('click','#clk_btn',function(){
            dd(123);
        });

Comment: From what source? You call the function with no parameters so it is undefined in the function

Comment: this is upto whatever you want to pass to next page just replace with 123 

did it work now or not ?

Comment: I am not the OP. I am simply pointing out the answer is incomplete

Comment: now code should be 



 <input type="button" value="Click me to open iframe" id="clk_btn"/>

</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#clk_btn',function(){
            dd(123);
        });
        var wo;
        function dd(id) {
            if (wo && !wo.closed) {
                // whatever you want to do here 
            }
            else {
                wo = window.open("iframe.php?lots="+id,"","width=200,height=200");      
            }
        }
    });
</script>

Comment: Edit the answer instead of pasting big blobs of unformatted code into comments

Comment: thanks for ur help guys,but i want to automatically add the iframe in the current window, for example i click it two times,the iframe in the current will become two,is it possible guys ? if its complicated its ok,because i searched in a whole day,but i can't find similar to my question,sorry for my bad english,by the way guys thank you for all the efforts. Godbless you all.

Comment: var randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1); 
                    window.open("new.php?lots="+id,"_blank",'PopUp',randomnumber,'scrollbars=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=850,height=500');


//replace code of window.open line